# injecting arbitrary HTML string into document (javascript) - updated

Tags: javascript, dom

Update: I just narrowed my problem to this:

Why doesn't this work:

```
var tmp = document.createElement('tbody');
tmp.innerHTML="<tr><td>hello</td></tr>";
```

tmp is getting the string hello. the tr and td html is lost (on FireFox).
Why is that? and how can I make such html injection work?

Original question:

I need to inject arbitrary HTML after a arbitrary element in arbitrary HTML documents.
I came across this method (inject the html string into dynamically generated div, get its firstchild element and insert it in the right place):

```
var tmp = document.createElement('div'); 
tmp.innerHTML = _injected_html;
var new_w = tmp.firstChild;
var parent = insertion_point.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(new_w, insertion_point.nextSibling);
```

The problem is that this does not work when trying to inject table elements. 
if the *injected* html is for example

```
"<tr> <td> table data </td> </tr>"
```

The `_tmp.innerHTML = _injected_html;` would not accept it (adding tr under div element).

Any idea how to make this work for any tag?

Comment: is insertion_point guaranteed to have a nextSibling (which might be null otherwise)?

Comment: you mean arbitrary not random surely?

Comment: yep. I meant arbitrary. fixing....

Answer (score 2):

Are you testing in IE by any chance? Most likely it does work in other browsers.

[Here's why](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html)

**edit:** Wait, you're inserting something into the table that looks like `<div><tr><td>`... that's not going to work. Why don't you replace the `document.createElement('div')` by `document.createElement('tr')`, and remove the `<tr>` tags from the `_injected_html`?

Something like this (tested in Firefox):

```
<script>
var i = 3;

function f() {
    var table = document.getElementById('someTable');
    var children = table.children[0].children;
    var after = children[Math.round(Math.random() * (children.length - 1))];
    var html = "<td>" + i++ + "</td>";

    g(html, after);
}

function g(_injected_html, insertion_point) {
    var tmp = document.createElement('tr'); 
    tmp.innerHTML = _injected_html;
    var new_w = tmp.firstChild;
    var parent = insertion_point.parentNode;
    parent.insertBefore(new_w, insertion_point.nextSibling);
}
</script>

<table id="someTable" onclick="f();">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

The second line of f() is a little awkward, but it gets the first child of the table (which is a `<tbody>`, and then its children (the actual `<tr>`s).

Comment: testing on FF at this point. Final solution should be completely cross browser

Comment: nice catch, do you know what IE versions are affected by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><td><lol/>
```

..isn't valid HTML! Containers are required for table rows/cols/heads, list items, definition lists and so on. Could you somehow validate the HTML for proper containers before injecting it?

Answer (score 0):

The following javascript will allow you to inject HTML/etc into the local page:

```
var example = "<p>test</p>"
document.body.appendChild(example);
```

That said, you **will** have to customize the code depending on **what** you are inserting.

Comment: TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Answer (score 0):

For a table, you must insert tr's into tbody.  When you write html

```
<table><tr><td>abc</td></tr></table>
```

IE, FF, Chrome, Safari at least (don't know about others directly) will modify this to be:

```
<table><tbody><tr><td>abc</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Therefore, something like:

```
var tmp = document.createElement('tr'); 
tmp.innerHTML = "<td>def</td>";
var new_w = tmp.firstChild;
var parent = insertion_point.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(new_w, insertion_point.nextSibling);
```

***if*** insertion_point is a tr tag.

But honestly, with Jquery there are more elegant ways of going about this as christina toma notes.

Comment: Thanks! Please see the update above. I don't think this is the problem. (+ I can't use jquery)